# Unit Testing using Moq and MVP-VM

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing, moq

I am trying to perform an Unit Testing(Integration Test using Moq) in my code using MVP-VM patterns. I have a view, a viewmodel, and a presenter.

The presenter holds the actual functionality of my UIs.

The way I was trying to test my presenter is, like following.

```
public interface IMockView : IRealView
{
        event EventHandler ButtonClickedEvent;
}

public interface IMockViewModel :  IRealViewModel 
{  }

public class MockPresenter  :  RealPresenter 
{
    private IMockView _view;
    private IMockViewModel _viewModel;
    public MyProperty { get; set; }

    public MockPresenter  (IMockView  view, IMockViewModel  viewModel) 
        :base(view, viewModel)
    {
        _view = view;
        _viewModel = viewModel;

        view.ButtonClickedEvent += (s, e) =>
                               {
                                     //Do Something 
                                     this.MyProperty = Property retrieved from db.     
                               };
    }
}
```

And here is my test code.(I am using NUnit Test framework with Moq)

```
    [Test]
    public void TriggerCreateClicked()
    {
        var view = new Mock<IMockView>();
        var viewModel = new Mock<IMockViewModel>();
        var presenter = new MockPresenter(view.Object,   viewModel.Object);

        viewModel.Setup(x => x.IsValid).Returns(true)
                 .Raises(t => t.ButtonClickedEvent += null, EventArgs.Empty);

        viewModel.Object.IsValid = true;

        Assert.NotNull(presenter.MyProperty);
    }
```

Basically, on my test case,

If ViewModel.IsValid returns true, I am raising the ButtonClickedEvent.
Then, inside of Presenter, I want to retrieve some property from db and store it in MyProperty. Then, I would like to test if this MyProperty is Not Null. If the test went through fine with no exception, presenter that has MyProperty should hold some values.

My question is, is it appropriate for me to create MockPresenter(not interface) that inherits RealPresenter(class) in order to perform Mock Test? Since my code in the RealPresenter does not provide any getters or setters to retrieve this Property, I decided to inherit RealPresenter by MockPresenter class in order not to impact on my RealPresenter. I have not seen any sample codes online that makes my approach feasible.

Answer (score 0):

The first question is whether you are testing only one thing in your test method. In your case, I think you are testing two things in one method: raising event when validation returns true and retrieving data when event is handled. I suggest  you separate them into two test methods.

The second question is you use Mock without verifying, which means all mocks in your test method is stubs. I guess in your method at least  you will verify one.

The third question is I did not get what your real logic since you put some additional logic in your mock interface and test method.

I think in unit testing of WPF with MVVM, you might not have to test raising event handler since that is .Net framework's job. What you need test is event handler works correctly. If it through command binding you can mock the command to test the calling if command's implementation contains dependencies such database connection.

Comment: Hello, Bill, Thank you for your answer. For your question,

Comment: I am testing only one thing that when user clicks on "Button" on the View, the presenter would raise the event that creates a table and insert it into database. That's why I raised this event on MockPresenter.

Comment: The reason why I would inherit RealPresenter through MockPresenter is that testmethod inside RealPresenter entails some other stuff that I don't need to test. So what I did was I created MockPresenter that includes the only testable portion(pretty much copy and paste from RealPresenter). Once I create this table through user clicking Button, on my test method, I would raise the event and retrieve that table I created from the db and check if this table is  retrieved correctly.

Comment: For your second question, I think you mean, I would say, view.verify(...) or viewModel.verify(...) Is that what you mean?  For your third question, on my view or viewModel interface, there is no other additional logic. Would you please advise me of whether the way I choose to do is appropriate for testing?

Comment: So the real logic is that user clicks a button on the View, Presenter handles the click event handler, where Presenter creates a table on the View, and when finished it retrieves the data. Since creating table is not testable, you create an event in your mock View and bypass creating table in your mock Presenter's event handler. Am I correct?

Comment: Another question is how you create the table in your button's event handler in the Presenter? Just calling a method on the View such as IView.CreatTable(...) or something else?

Comment: Bill, thanks for your quick reply. For your second question, the way I create the table is, in the MockPresenter, I would do this. var db = new DataContext(); var entity = new Entity(); db.Entities.InsertOnSubmit(entity); db.SubmitChanges();

Comment: For your first question on your second reply, as you know, presenter is not a Mock but a concrete class. When I raise the event from the test method, I would simulate the situation where user clicks the button to create the entity and place it in the db. And on my test, I would make sure that the entity I created is stored in db. Would it be appropriate for Unit Testing using moq?

Comment: I am talking implementation in production code, not test code. Since your test code contains logic, it is better to see how you implement in your production code. On one hand, you do not have to raise an event to test event handler in unit testing. You should test the event handler directly. This is what Commanding means in MVVM. On the other hand if your event handler contains logic talking to DB, you could extract this piece of logic to another method and make it virtual. In your mock Presenter, do nothing except overriding that method and provide your test doubles.